# the best way to extend a Backbone.Collection/View/Models

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I need to extend the backbone.collection with a collection of functions:

example:

```
var collection1 = Backbone.Collection.extend({});
var collection2 = Backbone.Collection.extend({});
```

should have the following custom methods:

```
console.log(collection1.method1); // function () {}
console.log(collection1.method2); // function () {}
```

On the other hand

```
var collection3 = Backbone.Collection.extend({});
```

should not have these methods.

```
console.log(collection3.method1); // undefined
```

How can I extend the Backbone.Collection just for collection1 and collection2 and not for collection3?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Following the Marionette example you should add properties or methods to the prototype property of an object class:

Anyway the following code is equivalent to @anto_byrma.
But the advantage of this approach is that you can extend collection or model or view in the same way.

```
var obj = {
    method1: function() {},
    method2: function() {}
};

var collection1 = Backbone.Collection.extend({});
var collection2 = Backbone.Model.extend({});
var collection3 = Backbone.Collection.extend({});

_.extend(collection1.prototype, obj);
_.extend(collection2.prototype, obj);
```

Answer (score 10):

Do you mean something like this:

```
var CustomCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    method1: function() {},
    method2: function() {}
});
var collection1 = CustomCollection.extend({});
var collection2 = CustomCollection.extend({});

var collection3 = Backbone.Collection.extend({});
```